# Contains() method of List<T>

Tags: c#, contains, generic-list

Precisely which methods in a Class are responsible for the `List<T>`'s  `Contains()` to operate?

I have overloaded == in my class. But it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will just call `Equals()` - that's all that needs to be overridden (or not, if you're happy with reference identity comparisons). If the type implements `IEquatable<T>` then that implementation will be used in preference to the general `Equals(object)` though.

In particular, from the documentation for [`List<T>.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx):

> This method determines equality using
>   the default equality comparer
>   `EqualityComparer(T).Default` for `T`, the
>   type of values in the list.

And from [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx):

> The `Default` property checks whether
>   type `T` implements the
>   `System.IEquatable(T)` generic interface
>   and if so returns an
>   `EqualityComparer(T)` that uses that
>   implementation. Otherwise it returns
>   an `EqualityComparer(T)` that uses the
>   overrides of `Object.Equals` and
>   `Object.GetHashCode` provided by `T`.

I don't believe it will use `GetHashCode` at all though.

Answer (score 2):

From the .NET guidelines - if you implement == always provide an implementation for object.Equals() and the != operator. The reason is that operators are not part of any interface and their use is not allowed in generic implementations (a List class cannot call the == operator on T because there is no guarantee that T will have the operator defined (see structs for example)).

Answer (score 1):

It will either call `Object.Equals()` or, if you have implemented, `IEquatable<T>.Equals()`:

```
private static EqualityComparer<T> CreateComparer()
{
    Type c = typeof(T);
    if (c == typeof(byte))
    {
        return (EqualityComparer<T>) new ByteEqualityComparer();
    }
    if (typeof(IEquatable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(c))
    {
        return (EqualityComparer<T>) typeof(GenericEqualityComparer<int>).TypeHandle.CreateInstanceForAnotherGenericParameter(c);
    }
    if (c.IsGenericType && (c.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)))
    {
        Type type2 = c.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        if (typeof(IEquatable<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { type2 }).IsAssignableFrom(type2))
        {
            return (EqualityComparer<T>) typeof(NullableEqualityComparer<int>).TypeHandle.CreateInstanceForAnotherGenericParameter(type2);
        }
    }
    return new ObjectEqualityComparer<T>();
}
```